# Django: Select from the dropdown the object that has the field is_active=True

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

i'm a newbie using django and i have a problem that cannot solve.
In my ServiceCreateView i need to select from the dropdown the object car that has the field is_active = true,
how can i acomplish that?

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.charfield(...)
    is_active= models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Service(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeingKey('Car'....)
    name = models.Charfield()

class ServiceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Service
    form = ServiceForm
    ...
```

If i change the field is_active to false in Car model, should not be shown in the dropdown.
can someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

This is how i solved it

```
from django import forms
from .models import Service, Car


    class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['car'].queryset = Car.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Service
            fields = ('car', 'name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the choices with the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class Service(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeingKey(
        'Car',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'is_active': True}
    )
    name = models.Charfield()
```

This is *not* enforced at the database level. It thus means that if you construct a `Service` object through the view and you select a `Car` that is at that moment `is_active=True`, then if later the `Car` is set to `is_active=False`, then the `Service` record will still exist and point to the inactive `Car`. This thus only has impact on the Django/Python layer that will only present `Car`s that are `is_active=True`, and furthermore the `ModelForm` will relect selecting `Car`s that are inactive.

Comment: Thanks! this is another way to solve my question... :)

Comment: @ApoloMachine: Well if it should be used on (nearly) all forms, I would set this in the `Service` model, since then there is no need to change all the `ModelForm`s, and the the `ModelAdmin` will also use this (you can of course define a custom `ModelForm` for the `ModelAdmin`, but this is more work), if it is more a one-off, then setting this in the `ModelForm` makes more sense :).